# How to check if a character is correct

Tags: java, boolean, character

I have a bunch of characters and want to remove everything that isn't a '#' '.' 'E' and 'G'.

I tried to use this:

```
if (buffer.get(buffertest) == 'G'|'E'|'#'|'.')
```

But got an issue with an incompatible type.

Comment: Have you already tried to use regular expression?

Comment: What is the return type of `buffer.get(buffertest)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (buffer.get(buffertest) == 'G'||
 buffer.get(buffertest) == 'E'||
 buffer.get(buffertest) == '#'||
 buffer.get(buffertest) == '.')
```

Comment: If the `get()` method updates the position in the buffer, than using this is pretty wrong.

Comment: `get()` only reads the position and does not change the state of the Buffer. see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html#get%28int%29 so I do not get your point.

Answer (score 4):

This root problem is incorrect use of the bitwise OR operator, and the Java operator precedence hierarchy. Java expressions of this type are evaluated left to right, and the == operator takes precedence over |. Which when combined, your expression roughly translates to:

```
(buffer.get(buffertest) == 'G') | 'E' | '#' | '.'
```

The first part of the expression `buffer.get(buffertest) == 'G' evaluates to a boolean.<br>
The second part of the expression`'E' | '#' | '.'` evaluates to an int, which is narrowed to a char

Which leads to an incompatible type compile time error. You can correct your code by expanding the check this way:

```
char ch = buffer.get(buffertest);
if(ch == 'G' || ch == 'E' || ch == '#' || ch == '.') {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: No, the RHS of Harry's expression evaluates to an int. If buffer.get(buffertest) would return a char, the code would compile. Obviously it does not.

Comment: You are partially correct, the RHS evaluates to the int result of the OR operation between all the operands. However, the expression will still not compile even if `buffer.get(buffertest)` returns a char. Updating answer.

Comment: You are right. The == operator takes precedence over the | operator. My mistake.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't shown the type of `buffer`, which makes things harder. But assuming `buffer.get` returns a `char`, you could use:

```
if ("GE#.".indexOf(buffer.get(buffertest) >= 0)
```

Or you could check each option explicitly, as per Simulant's answer... or to do the same thing but only calling `get` once:

```
char x = buffer.get(buffertest);
if (x == 'G' || x == 'E' || x == '#' || x == '.')
```

Your original code is failing because `|` is trying to perform a bitwise "OR" operation on the four characters... it's not the same thing as performing a logical "OR" on four *conditions*.

Comment: If `buffer.get(buffertest)` returns a `char` (as suspected), the first version of this code will fail, because `contains()` expects a `String` as a parameter. You need to convert it first to a `String`, as shown in my answer.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez: Changed to use `indexOf` instead of `contains`. I'd forgotten that the Java string API is pretty inflexible on that front :(

Answer (score 3):

You need to compare for each character individually. Assuming that `buffer.get(buffertest)` returns a `char`, here's how to do it:

```
char c = buffer.get(buffertest);
if (c == 'G' || c == 'E' || c == '#' || c == '.') {
    // do something
}
```

Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
char c = buffer.get(buffertest);
if ("GE#.".contains(Character.toString(c))) {
    // do something
}
```